# having a function run on stand-by

Tags: python, multithreading, gpio, standby

I am trying to find a way to have a function run in the background. If the button is pressed the function is triggered.

```
GPIO.input(22) == False
print("(----------------------------------------)")
print("--SYSTEEM UITGESCHAKELD \n--FIJNE DAG VERDER!")
print("(----------------------------------------)")
GPIO.output(22,0)
time.sleep(.23)
GPIO.output(22,1)
time.sleep(.23)
time.sleep(2)
GPIO.cleanup()
sys.exit(1)
```

I try it with an `if` and `else`. But that will loop forever. Is there something that makes the `def` run on the background and only triggers when the button is pressed.

Comment: As long as you're ok with the key being the enter key, you can pause the program with `input('Press enter to continue')`, and the program will only continue past that line when the user hits enter.

Comment: You need loop (ie. `while True`) which runs all the time and which periodically checks if button is pressed and then runs your function (`def`)